# How to catch changes to a cleared PersistentCollection?

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-odm

I am currently working on a very abstractly written Subscriber that should catch and process all sort of changes on any given Document.

While trying that I encountered an edge that I don't know how to handle:

1) My document keeps an embedMany collection of subdocuments.
2) I call `$document->collection->clear()`
3) I then flush

How can I catch the changes to the collection property ?

My subscriber currently reacts to doctrine's onFlush event. So far I have tried to following (all without success) :

- Iterating over ScheduledDocumentInsertions
- Iterating over ScheduledDocumentUpserts
- Iterating over ScheduledDocumentUpdates
- Iterating over the complete IdentityMap() and calling `$unitOfWork->getScheduledCollections($document)` for each document and try to find the change there

I seem to be unable to find the document or its collection in any of those cases. I strongly feel though, that doctrine should keep a reference to the collection if it plans to clear it of all content during the actual database commit.

I would gladly appreciate any help or hints towards a workable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received a pretty [extensive answer in the doctrine/mongo-odm github issue board](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/issues/1559).

TL;DR:

> However, if you need to know the elements that were present in the collection before clearing it, you're out of luck.

In summary:

If the collection has not yet been initialised (which I had to assume given that I wanted my subscriber to work under all circumstances) the whole collection will just be deleted without any knowledge as to what elements would be dropped in the process. As the collection will not by initialised before being dropped - this is done to maintain performance and reduce memory footprint.

The most feasible approach seems to be to [use a custom collection class](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/pull/1219) for the collection of embedded documents. This class can then handle the clear case in the expected manner.